# Mamp does not start mysql

Tags: mamp

I just done a new fresh install of mamp on my windows 10 and It doesn't start MySQL properlly.

[image]
[image]

This is mysql log :

```
2019-01-09T14:56:59.354340Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-01-09T14:56:59.355024Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 27324 ...
```

As you can see I have no issue (I think...)

This is my php log message when I try to use phpmyadmin:

```
[09-Jan-2019 14:57:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in Command line code on line 1
[09-Jan-2019 14:57:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in Command line code on line 1
[09-Jan-2019 14:57:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in Command line code on line 1
[09-Jan-2019 14:57:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in Command line code on line 1
```

It's default login and password (root and root)
I checked with a new port (3307) it's same

Someone have any idea where that's can form?

I'm using php 7.2.10 and MySQL 5.7.24 with apache

Thank you for your help

PS: I deleted ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1 and ibdata1

Answer (score 1):

delete: mysql-bin.index 
and it should work

Comment: This solution works for me though doesn't seem to be a permanent solution as I've had to delete it several times when MySQL refuses to start. The file is in C:\MAMP\db\mysql.

Comment: Exactly, I had to delete it every time I run MAMP, in my opinion using XAMP is much better and easier.

Comment: This also works for me. I find that MySQL is a bit flaky and doesn’t restart if it hasn’t shut down properly. This is in all installations, including a real one on a Linux server. However with MAMP, this appears to happen all the time. Normally deleting `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` fixed that for me, but with MAMP, I took your advice and deleted the `index` file.

Comment: Nothing has worked for me. Installing WAMP (XAMPP is a different set of tools/services while WAMP is the same as MAMP) works, even though it does not look/act as sleek.

Comment: my advice: stick to XAMPP